# Add number or text left of itemize list

Tags: captions, itemize, columns

I'm trying to find out out to add what I guess is a caption to an itemize list that looks like the following:

```
    - Thing
    - Thing
(1) - Thing
    - Thing
    - Thing
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this, would I use columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Code**

Simply use two minipages side by side. Adjust widths to suit your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[m]{0.15\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \Huge 1
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[m]{0.8\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Thing 
  \item Thing 
  \item Thing 
  \item Thing 
  \item Thing
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image]